# designing a large compressible binary float in Fortran

Tags: fortran, missing-data, netcdf

I would like to design a "fill" value for 4 and 8 byte float variables in a netcdf file to represent a special case of missing data. There is already a constant NF_FILL_FLOAT and my understanding about its design is that besides being a large, strange value it has a very compressible bit pattern. I believe it is different than huge(x). I already use NF_FILL_FLOAT to fill missing values -- my value has to be distinguishable. How do I go about this? What are the considerations for compression? Thanks.

Comment: The first obvious think to fo is to examine the value of NF_FILL_FLOAT as a real number and as a bit pattern. What are the reults of your investigations?

Comment: personnaly, I always use the value -123456789 which is OK as integer or real with 4 or 8 bytes. The probability to match a true value is so low ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about if you take NF_FILL_FLOAT and divide it by 2**n, where n is an integer >=0 ? This would give you "n" individual "fill values" and essentially the division is simply shifting the bits by n, so should still be compressible.

(Of course, if you write out to a netcdf, then external software is only designed to recognise one value of MISSING, so your fill values would not be recognised).